# algorithmic way to identify potential primary key / foreign key relationships in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a lot of tables in PostgreSQL with a lot of columns per table. I need to write a program that can identify the columns that can be a potential primary and foreign key pair.

I am iterating through every combination and comparing columns based on their distinct data. Pseudocode:

```
for (int i=0;i<cols.size;i++)
{
   for (int j=0;j<cols.size;j++)
   {
      if (i != j && (isNotAlreadyVisited(i,j) && isNotAlreadyVisited(j,i)))
      {
         QueryDistinctDataAndCompareCols(i,j)
      }
   }
}
```

In the QueryDistinctDataAndCompareCols() method I get the distinct values of both the columns as sets and get the mismatch count between the columns, with which I come up with a score that represents whether they are eligible to be a PK-FK pair.

The number of iterations takes too much time when there are too many columns and too many tables. I also have to query the DB in each iteration to get the distinct values of the column.

What is a faster and scalable solution either in the app tier or in the DB tier?

The number of columns and tables can be more than 5000 and 1000 respectively in some cases with more than 5000 distinct values per column.

It'll be acceptable if I have to precompute derived data before starting this processing.

Comment: Given the number of tables and columns, this is not a tractable problem: the search space is much too large. Even if each potential column pair could be evaluated in 1 microsecond (extremely unlikely), it would take more than 9.5 months to process 5000 tables with 1000 columns each. The search space can be pruned by identifying potential primary/unique key columns by eliminating those with duplicated values and identifying column pairs of compatible types such that a foreign key relationship is possible. Expanding the search to include many-to-many relationships is even less tractable.

Comment: The number of columns won't exceed 1600 because that is a PostgreSQL hard limit. This limit is further reduced by the requirement that fixed length columns must fit within the heap storage block size of 8192 bytes of which a portiion is occupied by the tuple header. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html for additional details on PostgreSQL's limits..

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask around for documentation. Someone built those tables, there's a chance there's a doc, a repo, a script, someone's `.psql_history` that can tell you what's what.
2. The problem sounds like you're dealing with a set of tables that have no constraints in place, but it's not explicitly stated so it might be worth just checking [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html).
3. Assuming both of the above failed, there's really no other way to do this other than what you're doing now: extracting and comparing counts and distinct values per column or a combination thereof. There are tools like [Dataiku](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/explore/analyze.html) that can help in exploratory analysis.
4. What those tools do to speed things up and what you can do yourself is sample. You can pull 1000 rows or less and eliminate most non-unique columns already based on that small subset:

   ```
   with samples as (select * from t1 limit 100),
   select c1,c2,c3,c4,count(*) from samples 
   group by cube(c1,c2,c3,c4) having count(*)>1;
   ```

   [`group by cube ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) lets you inspect counts of all combinations of fields. This leaves only a few columns per table as potential candidates for a PK.
5. Once you have some PK candidates, you can iterate through [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) and try to define the `unique constraint` that would be necessary for primary and foreign keys to work, then take note of the combinations that allowed you to do so, discarding the ones that report an `ERROR:  could not create unique index "c1c2" DETAIL:  Key (c1, c2)=(3, 3) is duplicated.`
6. Once you have the PKs, you can look for them in other tables

   ```sql
   select count(*) from t1 where exists (select from t2 where t1.nonpk=t2.pk);
   ```

After you're done, make sure to set up proper constraints to solidify all this in DDL and document it.

Comment: Identification of unique columns is not the only issue here. The bigger problem is matching those columns with the appropriate foreign key pairs.